# Interpolating between SVGs

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing, procedural, interpolation

I am very new to Blender.

I am trying to create a mesh model to eventually 3D print. I have imported 3 different SVG files, each one is a frame from a video of a running horse. I want to connect the edges of each of these horses so that they form a solid model that looks like a pillar with warped geometry. The idea I'm going for is to "3D print an video".

In general, the head of the horse should connect with the one below it, the head of the rider should connect with the one below it, the tail should connect with the one below it, and so on. I would call this an interpolation between planes, but that term seems to appear as an animation feature in Blender already.

1. Is there a way I can have Blender procedurally connect the "edge loops" (I'm not sure if I'm using this word correctly) of each of these parallel SVGs?
2. As I have researched this I have figured out that the SVG needs to be converted to a mesh if I am to do anything. When I do that though Blender generated an enormous amount of triangles on the plane, as shown in the second image. I imagine I won't want that -- what's the workaround?

Thanks

[image: stacking image, interpolation?]
[image: bad triangles!]

Comment: Hey buddy , i can understand you are new and don't know the terminology but i am finding it hard to decipher what you mean , Interpolation in animation means ** making your movements either smooth or constant** like if you move an object from 1 vector location to another in 10 frames if its not Bezier -  interpolated and is linear , it will move constantly but in Bezier interpolated mode it will be slow at the start and ending to make it look smooth SO probably interpolation is not the correct word you are looking for please some more info could help

Comment: @SHikhaMittal i believe the term interpolation is correct here. Think of the outline as shape keys, the transitions between shape keys would be interpolation.

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Yes interpolation can mean smoothing movement over time. Here I am describing an interpolation over space. A linear interpolation between each of these SVGs will probably look like straight lines. A bezier interpolation between each would look curvy, like the side of a vase. Do you know of a way to connect these edges?

I've researched and found the shortcut key "F" essentially "linearly interpolates" i.e. connects two+ vertexes in space. Is there an "F" key equivalent to two different plane shapes?

Comment: BTW I have since discovered that the term I mean is "lofting".

Comment: @Temmeh the f key is for Fill to fill a vertex between 2 edges or to fill a face between 4 empty edges , its not interpolation

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up I have discovered the "Bridge Edge Loops" tool in Blender, which is what I was looking for.